# What's the name of the point where you are closest or furthest from the ecliptic?

Tags: ecliptic

Every 24 hour day, there is a point as the earth rotates about its axis, where a location on earth is the closest to the ecliptic and where it's the furthest. Do those two points have a name?

What I mean is on the plane of the ecliptic, as the earth rotates around its axis, a point on the earth at 45 deg north is going to hit a low-point perpendicular to that plane, and will hit a high point perpendicular to that plane.

Comment: The Poles do not have such a point.  Any point on the Equator moves equal distances above and below the ecliptic...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a standard term for that quantity, but I'd call it the [ecliptic latitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ecliptic_coordinate_system) of the zenith.
With north positive and south negative, this would reach a minimum at 6:00 and a maximum at 18:00 local [sidereal time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sidereal_time).
These correspond to local solar noon or midnight at the solstices and occur 2 hours earlier per month.

The vectors perpendicular to the ecliptic are called the [ecliptic poles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ecliptic_pole). The zenith only coincides with one of these on the Arctic or Antarctic circle, at sunrise (winter-spring) or sunset (summer-fall).